# How to pass parameter from Ajax to C# using header request?

Tags: c#, ajax, header

I have the following request:

```
var response = $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    contentType: "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
    url: this.AgentServiceUrl + "/" + methodName,
    data: data,
    async: this.Async,
    success: function (xml, textStatus) { if (successHandler != null) successHandler(state, $.xml2json(xml), textStatus); },
    error: function (xmlHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) { if (errorHandler != null) errorHandler(state, xmlHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown); }
});
```

I want to add to a variable to this request header and consume it on C#,

I try many ways but I can't consume it on C#:

1. ```
    beforeSend: function (req)  
    {  
        req.setRequestHeader("AgentGUID", this.AgentGUID);  
    },
   ```
2. Pass `parameters:`

Can you help me? I don't want to change the function at the C# part I just want to use something like:

```
(System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Request.Headers["someHeader"]
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your `beforeSend` should work as you wish, but the reason you are not getting the value on server side is that `this.AgentGUID` on this method call is `undefined` because `this` in that context is pointing to another object (most probably ajax request object).

By defining a variable outside your ajax call you issue will be fixed.

```
var me = this;
var response = $.ajax({
    ...
    beforeSend: function (req)
    {
        req.setRequestHeader("AgentGUID", me.AgentGUID);
    },
    ...
});
```

Comment: Your server side code (c# code) is correct. just use "AgentGUID" key to get your value.